# Filemaker tabled xml export of related items

Tags: xml, filemaker

Exporting a Filemaker 13 table: in order to collect relational records (michael.hor257k helped me tremendously) my xslt template looks like:

```
<subitems>
    <xsl:for-each select="fm:item_number/fm:DATA">
        <xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
        <subitem>
        <item_number>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </item_number>
        <item_name>
            <xsl:value-of select="../../fm:item_name/fm:DATA[$i]"/>
        </item_name>
        </subitem>
    </xsl:for-each>
</subitems>
```

For a lay-out reason I need the related data to flow into Indesign table cells:

```
<table_related xmlns:aid="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeInDesign/4.0/" aid:table="table" aid:trows="??" aid:tcols="1">
<xsl:variable name="i" select="position()" />
<xsl:for-each select="fm:item_number/fm:DATA">   
   <cell_related aid:table="cell" aid:crows="1" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="250">
      <item_number><xsl:value-of select="."/></item_number>
      <item_name><xsl:value-of select="../../fm:item_name/fm:DATA[$i]"/</item_name>
   </cell_related>
</xsl:for-each>
</table_related>
```

To get the correct formatting the table need the input of the number of rows (aid:trows="??")
The number of related records varies, ergo the number of table rows varies.
How to get the number of related records on the postion of the question marks?
EDIT: made a typo.. of course the ?? need to go in the table specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make your questions self-sufficient and don't rely on us knowing more than what you actually posted.

The number of related records can be determined by counting the `DATA` elements that are children of a related field. I am not sure why you need to repeat this fact for every cell. In any case, in order to avoid repeated counts, define a variable **while you're still in the context of `ROW`** as:

```
<xsl:variable name="count-rows" select="count(fm:item_number/fm:DATA)" />
```

then use this variable where needed:

```
<cell_related aid:table="cell" aid:crows="{$count-rows}" aid:ccols="1" aid:ccolwidth="250">
```

Comment: thank you. I works now! Your " I am not sure why you need to repeat this fact for every cell." triggered me to find the typo.